# Are "Live Races" actually dynamically generated levels?

Tags: grid-2

In Grid 2, one of the race types is called "Live Race", your engineer informs you that these races can change at any time and you're not provided with a map, which implies that these races are dynamically generated levels.

However, I've found that if I restart one of these races, I always seem, to get an identical track. Is it that these tracks are generated and then reused in the event you restart the race or are these actually not dynamically generated tracks at all?

Are "Live Races" actually dynamically generated levels?

Comment: I was thinking this too. They feel the same, although I've not tried the same race twice, going back to the menu between races to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting a race doesn't re-load the level. Perhaps the manager's explanation is a little misleading, in that they don't really change at on the fly because they're generated before you play them. The liveroutes stitch together a bunch of 'pieces' of track from an area, and that generation is random, as far as I can tell.

They way I understand it working is that the entire route is planned out when the game is loading the map, and then you race on it, rather than it being done dynamically as you're driving. The route then doesn't change when you just pick "restart" to cut down on load times; if it generated an entirely new layout, you'd be waiting 15 seconds to load when you restart rather than it being instantaneous. If you exit out of the race, back to the menus, and then load it again, the track should be different. You'll likely start in a different spot on the map, but you'll probably recognize some of the corners and areas if you've done a race there prior.

Answer (score 1):

They are not dynamic, but predefined. You can check the variations in **\tracks\locations\cities\city_name\route#\dynamic_routes.xml**

Please note that altering this file will result in loss of Racenet connectivity and therefore no recorded race times or Steam achievements.